# Alipay sandbox | notify_verify response issue | Invalid partner

Tags: php, alipay

I have been trying to build an `Alipay` payment plugin for WooCommerce. I use credentials obtained from `https://isandbox.alipaydev.com/`. This website provides both `Buyer account` credentials and `Merchant account` credentials. I used `Merchant account` credentials for backend (integrated with plugin) and use `Buyer account` for the purchase.

When I make a purchase `Alipay` website says payment was successful and but when the plugin tries to verify the payment using `notify_verify` URL (`http://notify.alipay.com/trade/notify_query.do?`) their response always returns `false`.

When I try with a different verification URL (`https://mapi.alipay.com/gateway.do?service=notify_verify&`) they respond with

```
<alipay>
<is_success>F</is_success>
<error>ILLEGAL_PARTNER</error>
</alipay>
```

My question is if it was an illegal partner, how was I able to make a payment which was generated by same `partnerId`?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying wrong URL.

For test purposes you should use `https://openapi.alipaydev.com/gateway.do?`